# How to handle word-wrap inconsistency between Safari and Chrome?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-feistel-e7p00?file=/src/App.js) where the text wraps differently on Chrome vs Safari. I need to make the browsers wrap text consistently.

In Safari, there's room for the `sit` before the break

[image: Safari]

But in Chrome, it breaks before the `sit`

[image: Chrome]

Comment: There is a great article about that https://chenhuijing.com/blog/about-subpixel-rendering-in-browsers/

Comment: How is this affecting your application? The word wrap will depend on the user agent, the fonts available, and the user's font scaling.

Comment: @evelynhathaway - I need the text to wrap consistently between browsers. The div containing the text can change size, but the word-wrap needs to be consistent.

Comment: The word wrap will never be exactly the same depending on those factors I mention. It is likely to be a fool's errand to try honestly.